# NSDate from string...?

Tags: iphone

I am working on calendar  application. In this i have some issues with date format..

I am conflicting with two types of date formats..

one is -- 02-10-2010

second is - 02 Oct, 2010

but i want these formats be same..

any methods to convert from one format to second or second to first..
i searched date from string..but i cannot understand...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];  
[dateFormat release];

but it always shows Jan 10,2010  why this...the date i am passing here is 2010-10-08..